# C++ file input stream: reading "large" integers

Tags: c++, input

I have the following code:

```
void readFile(BST *tree) {
    ifstream infile("input.txt");
    long int sid, t;
    string l, f, h;
    while (infile >> sid >> l >> f >> h >> t) {
    // The line below is for debug purposes
    cout << "\"" << sid << "\" \"" << l << "\" \"" << f << "\" \"" << h << "\" \"" << t << "\"" << endl;
        tree->insert(sid, l, f, h, t);
    }
    infile.close();
}
```

Here is an example line:

```
78832112 Bruno Nicholas 32_Sugar_Rd_PA_12345 3026821712
```

Interestingly my code doesn't read anything from this line. Even more interesting is that if I remove *any* digit from the last number it reads it just fine.

I have no idea what causes this behavior. Any ideas?

Comment: The limit for an integer is around 2,147,483,647 I think, so that's why it's not reading it and why it reads it when you remove any digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the number is too big for your platform's `long`... you can either use `uint64_t` or something like that to give your program more breathing space, and/or you have to *document* your file format and the restriction on the valid ranges of values that your format can support.

Never forget that programming is only one half of I/O. The other half is the documentation. I/O is nothing without a format specification.

Comment: Alternatively if you don't need numbers much bigger than the example and you don't need negative numbers, he could use `unsigned long` and it would work for the example.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: That only affords you *one* extra bit :-) Anyway, it doesn't release you from *documenting* your format. The longest native type in C++11 is `unsigned long long int` (at least 64bit), but you may have legitimate reasons to use something smaller.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a 64 bit integer to hold something that big. `long int` is 32 bits on most platforms. Depending on your compiler and platform, you could use `long long`, `int64_t` or whatever your compiler supports.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that the reads for `sid`, `l`, `f`, and `h` are filled in one at a time, in order, and so they actually succeed because the offending number at the end of the line hasn't been read yet so your statement "Interestingly my code doesn't read anything from this line" is incorrect. The program reads most of the line, but it couldn't handle the last integer so the entire read operation returned `false`, and you never get inside the loop to use the data you just read.

Comment: P.S. since people are pedantic around here, the operation doesn't actually return `false`, but discussing what it actually does return would take us a bit far afield.